# Как вызвать event у jsf?

Tags: javascript, java, веб-программирование, jsf, primefaces

Вопрос в следующем:

```
<p:ajax event="select" listener="#{bean.onSelect}" oncomplete="xxx(#{bean.m})" />
```

Обработчик события `select` из выбранного элемента достаёт параметр `m`, который после принимает функция `xxx`. Но, как вы понимаете, `oncomplete` вызывается раньше, и поле `m` подтягивается пустым. Как можно решить эту проблему? Можно ли в **jsf** как то выкинуть руками событие селекта, после чего перейти непосредственно к клиенту? Или есть более элегантные решения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну раз уж используете Primefaces, то можете выполнить javascript из своего обработчика

```
...
public void onSelect(SelectEvent event) {
    setM(event.getObject());
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("xxx(" + getM() +")");
}
...
```

Таким нехитрым образом скрипт будет передан клиенту для исполнения. Что случится, понятное дело, после завершения обработки.

И ещё. `oncomplete` вызывается не раньше обработчика, а после.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20146630/execution-order-of-events-when-pressing-primefaces-pcommandbutton
Проблема только в том, что `m` действительно имеет старое значение, которое у неё было во время отрисовки страницы. А вновь выбранное `m` таким образом в скрипт не передать.

Если не нужна обработка выбора на сервере, то можно посмотреть клиентское api компонента. Может там предусмотрены клиентские события и api для извлечения элементов.

Answer (score 3):

Содержимое обработчика `oncomplete` заполняется раньше, чем появляется актуальное значение поля `m`, а если точнее, EL-выражение обрабатывается в момент отрисовки компонента (rendering), а не в момент срабатывания события "select".

Варианты решения данной проблемы зависят от конкретной цели. Возможно нет надобности получать из бина поле `m`, и выполнить все в `onSelect` методе бина.

Если же на стороне клиента все-таки необходимо получить данные из бина, то следует разместить на странице `h:inputHidden` / `h:outputText`  со ссылкой на требуемое поле, и обновлять его после события. Значение поля будет доступно на момент вызова скрипта `oncomplete`, останется только получить это значение с помощью javascript.

```
<h:outputText id="someStringDataId" 
              value="#{bean.m}" 
              binding="#{someStringData}" />
...
<p:ajax event="select" 
        listener="#{bean.onSelect}" 
        update="someStringDataId"
        oncomplete="xxx(document.getElementById('#{someStringData.clientId}').textContent)" />
```

Comment: Спасибо @Sergey, исправил ответ, неправильно выразился.